# Is the common house gecko poisonous to touch?

Tags: zoology

I live in India. Sometimes some common house geckos came in house and my family members kill them and I feel very bad (I even cried once ). They told me that It is very poisonous and toxic. If they fell in food or water, the water or food becomes toxic and would kill you. They told me that if you want to save them then catch them and release somewhere else but should I touch it?

I just saw a [man on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4BItRq5fdU) who handled it like it was no big deal?
I am talking about this gecko :- [image]

Comment: Actually, there are two poisonous lizards in the world. The other is Heloderma horridum, also from Mexico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are completely harmless. There are no poisonous lizards in India, and only one species of poisonous lizard in the world (*Heloderma suspectum*, from Mexico and SW U.S.). A gecko's skin is not toxic. They don't inflict a painful bite. The best way to hold a lizard without harming it is by the base of a hind leg.